# Normally open check valve

Tags: valves

What I'm looking for is basically an always open check valve that closes at a certain pressure. ~5psi.

The application is a breather vent that closes if the valve is submerged in water. Would a biased shuttle valve work? My only issue with that is water coming in the outlet port and the inlet port at the same pressure. No idea where the ball check would end up.

Has to be mechanical.

Comment: Please add a sketch of what you a really doing. I have no idea what 5 psi you are talking about. What piece of equipment is the breather attached to? Make and model of stuff is expected here. So are dimensions, operating conditions, and end item use.

Comment: use a ball that floats an blocks an orifice, directional though.

Comment: An "always open" check valve will be always open and won't check anything. You mean "normally open". How do you expect to develop 5 psi across an open valve? Next you have water in the inlet and outlet ports but you're venting air. The question is rather confused as is the title. Hit the [Edit] link ...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. You're right. Normally open. Valve is going on a transmission case.  Customer states they want the valve to breath freely both in and out but be protected against storm surges that would flood the unit underwater. The 5psi would come from the head pressure in any resulting flooding. I'm trying to steer them in a normally open solenoid valve that closes when power is cut (when the machine is turned off). They are insisting on a compact mechanical device. ~2" x 2".

Comment: OK, but all that information belongs in the question, not buried in the comments. "*My only issue with that is water coming in the outlet port and the inlet port at the same pressure.*" If there is no pressure differential there will be no flow.

Comment: Use a different mechanism than pressure differential.  Water is dense so a balloon filled with air would float up in its presence.  Once the valve becomes closed, will both sides still have water?